# Scrapy not saving scraped items

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Here is how I start my spider:

```py
    with resources.path(SCRAPING_MANIFESTS['systems'], 'manifest.jl') as path:
        process = CrawlerProcess({
            'FEEDS': {
                path: {
                    'format': 'jsonlines',
                    'overwrite': True,
                    'indent': 4
                }
            }
        })

        process.crawl(SystemsManifestSpider, prev_hashes=prev_list)
        process.start()
```

I verified in debug that indeed the path is correct and points to an existing file that I set to overwrite. It's a local file.

When I debug my spider, I see my item is being successfully populated. I populate it as such:

```py
MyCustomItem(scrapy.Item):
    my_field = scrapy.Field()


# inside my spider class defined as SystemsManifestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    while True:
    
        ...

        my_item = MyCustomItem()
        my_item['my_field'] = "test"

        ...

        print(my_item)  # prints the dictionary with 'my_field' correctly populated
        yield my_item
```

And the debug output after letting it run a while:
 `'item_scraped_count': 9`

It correctly accesses the webpage and scrapes the data verified in debug, but after the item is yielded it doesn't save anything to my `manifest.jl`.

However, when I modify it to this:

```py
process = CrawlerProcess({
        'FEEDS': {
            Path("./manifest.jsonlines"): {
                'format': 'jsonlines',
                'overwrite': True,
                'indent': 4
            }
        }
    })
```

It correctly creates a new file and saves it at the local directory where I run the code. Both paths lead to a real file and directory.

But again when I specify an absolute path, it doesn't work:

```py
process = CrawlerProcess({
        'FEEDS': {
            Path("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\PycharmProjects\\xxxx\\src\\python_scrapper_nf\\xxxx\\manifest.jsonlines"): {
                'format': 'jsonlines',
                'overwrite': True,
                'indent': 4
            }
        }
    })
```

The path above is identical to `Path(./manifest.jsonlines)`

Note: It seems all relative paths work, but absolute paths never do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, @Alexander is completely right.

There is a fix that may come in future versions. You can follow this: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/5971. With this, Windows paths will be better handled and if it cannot determine the correct storage, it will default to file storage, which will work in your case.

Also, if you prepend `file:///` to your path, I think it might work.

:)

Comment: It sadly didn't work with that but I'm happy it's getting worked on!

Answer (score 2):

You are partially correct.  Using absolute paths on Windows OS does not work. This is mentioned in the Scrapy documentation in the [Feed Export](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#storage-backends) section:

> Storage backends
>
> Local filesystem
>
> The feeds are stored in the local filesystem.
>
> URI scheme: file
>
> Example URI: file:///tmp/export.csv
>
> Required external libraries: none
>
> Note that for the local filesystem storage (only) you can omit the scheme if you specify an absolute path like /tmp/export.csv. This only works on Unix systems though.

Its also mentioned later on the same page that you can use a `pathlib.Path` object instead, however using a Windows absolute `pathlib.Path` object still will not work.

The reason why this is the case is because `scrapy` parses the field looking for the `URI` scheme. However when it detects that there is no scheme then it assumes that it is a local filesystem path.  Unfortunately Windows absolute paths have drive letters as roots that the `URI` parser interprets as an unrecognized scheme which causes it to silently ignore the feed export location.

Comment: How would we fix this so that we can still use importlib with resources?

Comment: @JackAvante  I am not certain what you mean.